# Should users be given a chance to correct their old answers before flagging?

Tags: discussion, flags, answers, link-only-answers

Should users be given a chance to correct their old answers before flagging?

I've been having a (too meta admittedly) with another user on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7564880/1348195) which is a 3 years old answer by [Darin Dimitrov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/29407/darin-dimitrov).

We disagree on whether or not old link only answers should be flagged immediately or a grace period should be given to the author if there is reasonable reason to believe they will fix it themselves.

Link only answers were accepted a while ago and they are not anymore.

I think that if the answer is old (2012 and older) the user should be given a comment (by the user who wants to flag) for a day before the answer should be flagged, the justification is:

- It gives the user a chance to improve their answer first. Trustworthy high rep users are very likely to be disciplined enough to delete the post if they won't improve it.
- It does not clutter the flag queue and does not add work load on the mods.
- It does not use disciplinary means as the first options, rather, it gives users a chance to solve the problem themselves without involving the whole 'system'.
- It's basically 'the problem solving itself'.

Comment: (Also, I'm honestly hoping that the arguments against this are not 'getting the flag count up for a badge')

Comment: I think you're totally right. Don't have much to add except "Go ahead and do this". :)

Comment: Related meta chat discussion on the subject - http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1828652#1828652

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum that's not really a discussion :)

Comment: @psubsee2003 what do you mean?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum what I mean is the discussion seems rather 1 sided, only you were really debating the issue

Comment: @psubsee2003 he was raising some interesting arguments too in my opinion (about undeletion). I asked him to participate in the discussion in this thread several times and he seems uninterested - hopefully, someone with the same stance will take the time to formulate an answer.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum yes, stuff can get undeleted after it is fixed, but when you flag, it is usually the mod doing the deleting, which means, you need a mod to undelete.  So to fix the post after deletion, you now need to involve a mod twice.  I think it is almost always better to comment first, then flag.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree. However, some users don't and I'm interested in their opinions too.

Answer (score 7):

OK, Benjamin poked me enough to write my opinion in here, so I will try to quickly summarize it up.

I would like to point that out I was not the first person downvoting the answer, nor the one flagging it first, so I did not bring any more overhead into the system for this case in that sense.

I had also asked in [Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1828600#1828600) what to do before acting, and then I followed the quick consensus.

The answer also seems to be deleted for now by 20K+ users. For those who cannot see it, it was basically a link-only answer.

[image]

The question seems to be boiling down whether it is more chancy that it causes a moderator overhead than not.

In my opinion and experience, it is more chancy that 20K+ or even 20K- users reach consensus about deleting poor answers, which means that the moderators will not be included in the clean-up.

Unfortunately, we need to get the 20K+ users' attention somehow, and the only way I can think of is flagging or coming to meta maybe. The latter reads a bit more overhead than the first.

I think, based on the discussion with Benjamin, we all agree that deletion is fine by non-moderators. Please let me know if I misunderstood it.

So, I think it is a system issue personally if flagging is not the right way to get their attention, and there is nothing better. If that is the case - which is not in my experience -, in my opinion, we would need to find a simple way for that.

I have seen 5-10 posts like that in the near post deleted almost instantly by 20K+ users, including the mentioned Jon Skeet answer, so my personal experience shows that it works smoothly in the practice without moderator intervention.

[image]

I am personally more worried about the waiting period since we so many posts to clean up on Stack Overflow that we cannot (at least I cannot) book keep them all. It is more productive and effective for me if only the actually edited and fixed posts come back with undeletion than watching all of them on a regular basis whether they would get updated or not, and hence require further actions.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian the point is: there is no moderator overhead because the 20k users can handle it from the flag queue just fine. On the other hand, waiting causes way too much overhead for those who wait for the cleanup to (not) happen.

Answer (score -2):

May be user atleast be notify before flagging and given some time for his corrections.After that fragging process should be done.

Comment: That's the opposing suggestion. The other answer explains why this is not practical.